# how to check value of <input> field if a certain text still exist in javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

how do you check if a string/text still exist in an HTML element particularly `<input>`?

i have this code `$("input").bind('paste', function(e) {` that captures paste events and checks if the pasted text contains a youtube url, parse it via regex and simply print the youtube url in a `<div>` element.

how can i make javascript to delete the printed data, if the link is removed/deleted in the input element

here is a sample: http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvr4/5/

input any youtube url in the textfield, and it should display something. then remove the url, the data still remains.

basically i just want the printed output to disappear once the existence of the url is removed in my input

initial thought was adding some `onChange` event to the `input` but im not quite sure how can i do it without messing the current code.

Comment: Have you tried binding a .keyup?

Comment: yes. i did already. but the problem with that. it recognizes the `ctrl` and `v` so it prints the result twice. and pasting using mouse is not recognized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this with `keyup event` like

```
$("#input").on({
    'paste': function (e) {
        $("#print").html('');
        var val = e.originalEvent.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');
        if (youtube.test(val)) {
            var yurl = val.match(youtube)[0];
            $("#print").html(yurl);
        }
    },
        'keyup': function (e) {
        $("#print").html('');
        var val = this.value;
        if (youtube.test(val)) {
            var yurl = val.match(youtube)[0];
            $("#print").html(yurl);
        }
    }
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8Pvr4/9/)